# Facebook graph api for page not returning response of emails

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hi I am using facebook graph API in order to access page details:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola?access_token=xxx
```

I am successfully getting all the fields but I am unable to get emails field.

However in documentation it is showing emails as a response.

[Facebook docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page)

Comment: access tokens should never be included...luckily, it is not valid anymore

Comment: Yes I know its not valid thus I posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to include the fields in the API call now:

`https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola?fields=emails&access_token=xxx`

Comment: Your are correct man, but why it is giving all fields but not the email one

Comment: it should actually not return all fields, but only a few (id, name).